# If I had a text file of values, how would I read that file?

Tags: c, file

I have to write a program that takes a single command-line argument. The argument should be the name of a file to open for reading (And if the argument is not provided or the file cannot be opened, then print an error message).

The program opens the file and reads each line until EOF is reached. Each line in the file has two double values representing a point on the coordinate plane For each of the lines, read the two values, create a point, and print that point if it is in the first quadrant of the coordinate plane. I'm a bit confused about what it means when it says "a single command-line argument", what does that mean? I tried writing the code for the program, but I'm not sure if I did it right.

When I try to compile my code, it keeps giving me these errors:

```
 file.c:3: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
 file.c:14: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
```

And here's my code:

```
#include "point.h"

FILE *open_file(char const name[], char const mode[])
{
   FILE *file = fopen(name, mode);

   if (file == NULL)
   {
      perror(name);
   }
   return file;
}

void point_in_Q1(FILE *in, FILE *out)
{
   double x, y;
   struct point p;
   int check;

   p = create_point(x, y);

   while (check != EOF)
   {
      if (p.x >= 0 && p.y >= 0)
      {
         fprintf(out, "%lf%lf", x, y);
         check = fscanf(in, "%lf%lf", &x, &y);
      }
   }
}
```

One more thing that I'm confused about, if I had a file with the values for the coordinate points named "test_points.c", would I have to put that in fopen(name, mode)? (In place of "name").

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will not know what `FILE` is if you don't:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

I. You are using the `check` variable uninitialized;

II. `while (!eof)` is almost always the wrong approach to reading a file;

III. The compiler errors are not quite easy for us to resolve without you providing the header file too.

IV. To your last question: obviously you use the name of whichever file contains the data (what else?).

Comment: So, when I include the name of the file, how would I state it? I tried just putting in "test_points" in place of "name" on lines 2 and 6, but the compiler still complained. I'm a bit confused as to how I would pass the file to the fopen function.

Comment: If the compiler's still complaining about how 'test_points' is undeclared, how would I declare it? I know that to declare a double we would say: double a; and I know for an integer we would say int x;...but, how would I declare a text file?

Comment: @Karen I don't really understand your problem, it doesn't make sense. You open that file given by the file name, read data from it then close it. You use `fopen()`, then `fscanf()` or `fread()` or `fgets()` and `fclose()` for it. You seem to have little to no idea about what a file is nor how it is used. Go learn it, you do need some fundamentals. You can't build a house without having dug the foundation.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, we just learned about files today. :/ But I think I found my mistake...yeah, I'll definitely review my notes for files. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop seems problematic besides the fact that you are missing `#include <stdio.h>`.  If the `if` condition is not satisfied, you will stay in the loop forever.

You probably meant to move the `fscanf` out of the `if` scope.  Also, you will need to rebuild `p` based on the values read.

Comment: Actually, wait...is it possible to write a helper function to return the values for the points if they're both positive (in the first quadrant)? And then could I call this function in point_in_Q1 to simplify that block of code a little??

Comment: Sure, you can create a helper function, and possibly check the values for being positive in there as well.

Comment: So in my helper function, I checked p.x and p.y to see if it was positive (because I have a struct point p and inside the struct point, there are fields of double x and y), and I returned p if it was positive. But, in my else statement, I'm not sure what to return if it's negative...

Comment: That will be for you to decide.  What do you do if the value is negative.